Second monitor not remembered after KVM switch
I have a KVM switch so that I can switch monitors and peripherals between two laptops. One of those computers is running Ubuntu Linux while the other is a Windows PC. There is a widescreen monitor which is also controlled by the switch and used as a second monitor, plugged in via HDMI. I have Ubuntu configured to extend my display onto this second monitor, but every time I switch to the other PC and then subsequently switch back, it forgets my Display settings and only displays the Linux machine's built-in monitor. So then I have to click into Settings and reconfigure the second monitor all over again. Is there any way to essentially tell Ubuntu to 'remember' that second monitor configuration, whenever it re-detects the HDMI connection?
